# Do I need to write unit test for configuration constants?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, configuration

I am writing unit test cases using `karma-jasmine` for my `angular` application. I have a configuration `constant` something like this:

```
app.constant('Configuration', {
  BASE_URL: 'http://localhost:3030',
  SUPPORTED_BROWSERS: ['Chrome', 'Firefox', 'CriOs']
});
```

I need to test the unit test the `Configuration` constant. I don't know whether it makes sense or not testing a constant. My suits will be something like this:

```
describe('Configuration.SUPPORTED_BROWSERS', function() {

  it('should say only 3 browsers are supported', function() {
    expect(Configuration.SUPPORTED_BROWSERS.length).toBe(3);
  });
  it('should say crios is supported', function() {
    var temp = Configuration.SUPPORTED_BROWSERS.some(function(browser) {
      return browser.toLowerCase() === 'chrome';
    });
    expect(temp).toBe(true);
  });
  it('should say firefox is supported', function() {
    var temp = Configuration.SUPPORTED_BROWSERS.some(function(browser) {
      return browser.toLowerCase() === 'firefox';
    });
    expect(temp).toBe(true);
  });
  it('should say chrome is supported', function() {
    var temp = Configuration.SUPPORTED_BROWSERS.some(function(browser) {
      return browser.toLowerCase() === 'crios';
    });
    expect(temp).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I am not sure whether it is good to test something **which is constant, does not contain any logic and is hard coded**.

Comment: I do not think, it is a good practice to test "hard coded" array. Unit test is to test logic, conditions etc. It will not harm if You want to include the above test though.

Comment: Not to mention test has several bugs in it

Comment: @charlietfl I just wrote the psuedo code not working test suits.

Answer (score 2):

NO , Its not a good practice to write unit test cases for constants . Unit testing mainly done for the functionality and logic that it is working fine or not . For a constant there is no logic to check .